# How do we treat questions post with more than one question in it?

Tags: discussion

On TGO it is quite common to see questions containing several, sometimes whole lists of questions. On other sites this is considered very bad stile and even thematically related questions should be asked in separate posts.

My meta question was triggered by the following question:
[Is campfire smoke safe for inhalation and cooking?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8283/is-campfire-smoke-safe-for-inhalation-and-cooking)
As already indicated in the comments, I think we have to separate questions, that are no entity. Otherwise it gets very confusing for somebody visiting this question, as there are answers covering only parts of the question asked and as in whatsisname's case the one question, that is not answered by anyone else and not related to the question title.

The other argument:
We are currently on 1.41 questions per day, area51 suggests 10 to be a good number. So we would benefit in this regard, if we tried to shift the "asking-culture" towards the principle: One question, one post.

Is the current state intentional or should we try to change towards one question one post?

Comment: We already do try and encourage one question per post, sometimes by closing the question until it has been edited down to one and creating supplementary questions.

Answer (score 2):

A polite comment should be your first port of call try and get some communication with the user, they're likely not aware that they've done anything wrong.

If they don't edit or don't reply to your comment's (**given a reasonable amount of time, remember not everyone visits every da**y) then vote to close (*Too broad*). If you don't have vote to close you can flag a moderator to have a look.

Don't be afraid to downvote a bad questions either (we should likely try not to become SO where everyone is jumped on all the time, we're trying to grow they're trying to improve the question quality based on large volumes), but if a question is bad, then it should be downvoted. Democracy in action.